An urban low budget black film with three female friends
It's an urban low budget black film with three female friends. One was married to a rapper and was having an affair. The next was tired of being a side chick and looking for love. The third was a hustler who robbed rich men and ended up causing her friend's husband to get shot.
Movie released sometime in between 2000 and 2015.

More details regarding the vague time the movie was released

sometime from 2000 to now. Sorry that's the best I can do. It's an urban low budget film.

I have found it. It's called "Durdy Game".

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

@NapoleonWilson Seems the OP already found it. Vitamalt, you can answer your own question and approve the answer to resolve it.

@Walt Doesn't make the question any better, though.

OP responded to the 1st comment with an approximate time of release, which is still something, I guess.

I believe you're looking for Durdy Game (2002), which was shown at a number of film festivals and then released straight to DVD.

Losing faith in love, three seductive women (Tawny Dahl, Janisha
  Faith, Karima Holloway) work together to con unsuspecting men for
  money.

According to the description on Rotten Tomatoes, the film was supposedly inspired by actual events.
